# How to increase timeout for pupetteer's Page.pdf when getting "TimeoutError: waiting for Page.printToPDF failed"?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm getting "TimeoutError: waiting for Page.printToPDF failed" when trying to convert to PDF a large invoice:

> ```
> Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise { <rejected>
>  TimeoutError: waiting for Page.printToPDF failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded                                                      
>
>   at Object.waitWithTimeout (/var/www/montbeau/releases/20210929161149/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/helper.js:224:26)
>
>   at Page.createPDFStream (/var/www/montbeau/releases/20210929161149/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:2045:49)
>
>   at Page.pdf (/var/www/montbeau/releases/20210929161149/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:2057:37)
>
>   at /var/www/montbeau/releases/20210929161149/scripts/invoice_to_pdf.js:175:20
>
>   at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)                                                                                                                                                                                          
>   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)                                
>   } reason: TimeoutError: waiting for Page.printToPDF failed: timeout
>   30000ms exceeded                                                      
>
> at Object.waitWithTimeout (/var/www/montbeau/releases/20210929161149/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/helper.js:224:26)
>
> at Page.createPDFStream (/var/www/montbeau/releases/20210929161149/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:2045:49)
>
> at Page.pdf (/var/www/montbeau/releases/20210929161149/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:2057:37)
>
> at /var/www/montbeau/releases/20210929161149/scripts/invoice_to_pdf.js:175:20...
> ```

How do I increase the timeout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Julien mentioned, Set timeout to 0.

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.pdf({
    printBackground: true,
    displayHeaderFooter: false,
    timeout: 0,
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In `createPDFStream` method of `puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js`, timeout appears as an option:

```
2007         const { scale = 1, displayHeaderFooter = false, headerTemplate = '', footerTemplate = '', printBackground = false, landscapdscape = false, pageRanges = '', preferCSSPageSize = false, margin = {}, omitBackground = false, timeout = 30000, } = options;
[...]
2045         const result = await helper_js_1.helper.waitWithTimeout(printCommandPromise, 'Page.printToPDF', timeout);
```

So despite `timeout` not being a documented option at https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions, it does seem as though it is an option for the `.pdf` method.