# Is there a way to increase the timeout for puppeteer-report's pdfPage?

Tags: puppeteer

I know because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69436420/how-to-increase-timeout-for-pupetteers-page-pdf-when-getting-timeouterror-wai) you can pass 'timeout' as a PDFOption to change the timeout value of Page.pdf in regular puppeteer, but 'timeout' isn't listed as a PDFOption in puppeteer-report for the pdfPage function. Is there a way to change the timeout value to allow time for bigger reports?

Answer (score 0):

Update your puppeteer-report to version 3.0.2 or higher. This version has up to date PDFOptions. This was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to Puppeteer's documentation, by default the [PDFOptions](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.pdfoptions) the **timeout** should be 30_000 milliseconds (30 seconds). You can set an specific value on milliseconds by adding this option:

```
class Page {
  pdf(options?: PDFOptions): Promise<Buffer>;
}
```

Where PDFOptions will be something like

```
{
...,
timeout = 50000,
...
}
```